# Ppt Vba that Group Shapes Per Row / Column

Tags: vba6

I'm trying to create a macro, when selecting 4 x 4 shapes it will group the shapes in a row. and separate macro for column.

on't have time right now to write/test any code, but if I had to do this, I'd start with something like this snippet I had from another project:

Sub GroupCertainShapes()

```
Dim x As Long
Dim sTemp As String
Dim aShapeList() As String
Dim lShapeCount As Long

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    ' iterate through all shapes on the slide
    ' to get a count of shapes that meet our condition
    For x = 1 To .Shapes.Count
        ' Does the shape meet our condition? count it.
        If .Shapes(x).Type = msoAutoShape Then
            lShapeCount = lShapeCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' now we know how many elements to include in our array,
    ' so redim it:
    ReDim aShapeList(1 To lShapeCount)

    ' Reset the shape counter
    lShapeCount = 0

    ' Now add the shapes that meet our condition
    ' to the array:
    For x = 1 To .Shapes.Count
        ' cant get the correct condition (e.g. currentshape.top > lastshape.top)
        

    ' and finally form a group from the shapes in the array:
    If UBound(aShapeList) > 0 Then
        .Shapes.Range(aShapeList).Group
    End If

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.